# Match java-script files name using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, file, find

How I can match the following files name using `regex.`

`index.js`

`[id].js`

`[...params].js`

I tried this regex on my own but it seems to be not work

```
[a-z[]*.tsx


index.js // working
[id].js // not working
[...params].js // not working
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to validate JavaScript file names that have alphanumeric characters, and are optionally enclosed in `[`...`]` or `[...`...`]`. Based on this you can use this regex, here with a number of tests:

```js
[ 'index.js',
  '[id].js',
  '[foo].js',
  '[...params].js',
  '[..invalid1].js',
  '[invalid2.js',
  '#invalid3.js',
  'invalid^4.js',
  'invalid[5].js',
  '[(invalid)6].js',
  'invalid7.css',
].forEach(name => {
  let isValid = /^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+|\[(?:\.{3})?[a-zA-Z0-9]+\])\.js$/.test(name);
  console.log(name, '=>', isValid);
});
```

Output:

```
index.js => true
[id].js => true
[foo].js => true
[...params].js => true
[..invalid1].js => false
[invalid2.js => false
#invalid3.js => false
invalid^4.js => false
invalid[5].js => false
[(invalid)6].js => false
invalid7.css => false
```

Explanation of regex:

- `^` -- anchor pattern at start of string
- `(?:` -- start of non-capture group (for logical `or`)

  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` -- 1+ alphanumeric chars
- `|` -- logical `or`

  - `\[` -- literal `[`
  - `(?:\.{3})?` -- optional 3 dots
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` -- 1+ alphanumeric chars
  - `\]` -- literal `]`
- `)` -- end of non-capture group
- `\.js` -- literal `.js`
- `$` -- anchor pattern at end of string

To learn more about regex language: https://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Codev/TWikiPresentation2018x10x14Regex

Comment: @athena_odin: So, should `_index.js`, `$file.js`, `$.js` be valid as well?

Comment: no its not valid